neovim + lua + slimv: how to start swank server in the current folder/project?
I'm using Slimv with NVim, and it works perfectly except when attempting to (load ...) files from the same folder. I presume it's an issue with translating vim shell commands (with % expansions, etc.) to vim.cmd() lua functions.
I used to run Slimv with Vim and set g:slimv_swank_cmd to '!osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd %:p:h && sbcl --load ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/slimv/slime/start-swank.lisp""'. This would load sbcl at the current folder without an issue.
Now with neovim and using a Lua LazyVim config file, I have to call vim.cmd([[let g:slimv_swank_cmd='!osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"cd %:p:h && sbcl --load ~/.local/share/nvim/slimv/lazy/slime/start-swank.lisp\""']]), but apparently the placeholders for folder location cannot be resolved.
I'm guessing I'm missing something about how vim.cmd runs its argument.
Tangentially would also appreciate a more thorough answer regarding how people run Slimv so that it opens to a given folder/project and thus allows files to be loaded easily via relative paths.
